# Module filter by K2 tag (Joomla 2.5)

Tags: joomla2.5

I want to filter and display my K2 items by tag. I know i can do it by creating a menu item (selecting "tag" from the menu item creation options), BUT i want to display them in a module. Is there any way to do it?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Roksprocket module to achieve that, it has filter by tag as source option, it's free and works with k2. It's not my favorite but it does what you want.